# I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this Linear Algebra question.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem that says:

> Let $ V $ be the vector space $ \mathbb R ^ 2 $ and let $ T : \mathbb R ^ 2 \to \mathbb R ^ 2 $ be defined by
> $$ T ( \langle x , y \rangle ) = \begin {cases} \langle - 34 x , - 34 y \rangle & x \ne 0 \\ \langle 0 , 0 \rangle & x = 0 \end {cases} $$
> Is $ T $ linear?

I proved that $ T ( r u ) = r T ( u ) $ and $ T ( u + v ) = T ( u ) + T ( v ) $, but when I submitted that, it says it's wrong, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Are there values where this is not true?

Edit: I figured it out now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Hi Rhea. In the future, please use MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions. (You can check the updated text in your post to see how it works.)

Comment: Can you write a vector of the form $\langle 0,y \rangle$ where $y \neq 0$ in the form $\langle x_1,y_1 \rangle + \langle x_2,y_2 \rangle$?

Comment: $T(2(1,1))=T(2,2)=<-34(2),-34(2)>=2<-34,-34(2)>=2^2<-34,-34>=2^2T(1,1)$

Comment: I tried this and the answer and it didn't work... yet both make sense

Comment: @CSquared I have no clue what you're talking about here; the scaling property *does* hold for this transformation.

Comment: @Ian I don't understand what you mean by this

Comment: Which thing, my first comment or my second comment? With my second comment I was just saying that what CSquared said is wrong. The first comment was a hint about how to show that $T$ doesn't have the additivity property.

Comment: @Ian I meant the first comment; that was my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, try to write $\langle 0,1 \rangle$ as a sum of two vectors both with nonzero $x$ component. (Or you can go the other way, write a vector with a nonzero $x$ component as a sum of a vector with a nonzero $x$ component and another vector with a zero $x$ component.)

Comment: @Ian oh i see, i was under the impression that $<-34x,-34y>$ was an inner product.

Answer (score 1):

$$T(<1,0>)= <-34,0>$$
$$T(<0,1>)= <0,0>$$
$$T(<1,1>)= <-34,-34> \neq T(<1,0>)+T(<0,1>)$$